# Apache Camel null body for patch() API expose via rest() component

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, redhat, jbossfuse

I am trying to expose a patch API, using camel rest() component but in doing so when the exchange is formed there is not body attached to it. It shows as null, but the same config is working for POST, PUT call.

E.g. **.post("/path/subpath")
.type(Request.class)**
This is working and the incoming json is binded with the Request class but the same is not working for  patch def

E.g. **.patch("/path/subpath")
.type(Request.class)**
Body is null

Comment: Could you please show the full route with the rest configuration?

Comment: Yeah put up a reproducer somwwhere, like as a .zip file attached to a JIRA or put the code on github somewhere.